# Why the While loop continues and how to calculate the average based on numbers input?

Tags: python, while-loop

Hi I'm trying to solve this coding homework:

Write a program that always asks the user to enter a number. When the user enters the negative number -1, the program should stop requesting the user to enter a number. The program must then calculate the average of the numbers entered excluding the -1.

I define the while loop to make sure it keeps asking, as:

```
while n != -1
 str(input("enter your number:"))
```

But whenever I try to input -1, it just keeps on asking to enter the number regardless.
Also, I'm not sure what is the best way to define the average excluding -1, none of the lessons prior to this assignment talked about this. I have Googled about it but none of the examples match this particular assignment, even fumbling around did not help.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You’re nearly there, but you’ve cast the input to a string, but it’ll need to be a number (int or float). Down votes are likely because homework or no obviously formatted code. Next time, make code obvious with the formatting options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask for a number the if it is not equal to -1 enter the while loop. So the code would be:

```
n = float(input("What number?"))
if n != -1:
    sum += n
    nums_len = 1
    while n != -1:
        sum += 1
        nums_len += 1
        n = float(input("What number?"))
print("The average is", str(sum/nums_len))
```

Comment: I see, so I had to create an if statement to work around the -1, and then calculate the average with sum and nums_len, and only then make it loop. 
Upon inserting your code, it shows this error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/d14a825c3875f503/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    sum += n
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Comment: Try it again. I just edited it.

Comment: Still same error (I've thought also to change to float but it still does not like it)

Comment: If that doesn't work, change it to `sum = n`

Comment: Or you could also try changing the name of the variable as it might be mistaking it with a built in function, hence the error

Comment: I went with `sum = n` however, I'm not sure if it's giving the right average. I have tried input 2 2 2 2, then interrupting the loop with -1 and I've got result 1.2 rather than 2?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `n` is meant to be the user input, but you're never assigning a value to `n`. Did you mean to do this?

`n = str(input("enter your number:"))`

Also, you're comparing `n` to `-1`, but your input isn't a number; it's a string. You can either convert the input to a number via `n = int(input(...))`, or compare the input to a string: `while n != '-1'`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, this is the final code with the correct values that gives the average of user inputs

```
n = float(input("What number?"))
if n != -1:
    sum = 0
    nums_len = 0
    while n != -1:
        sum += n
        nums_len += 1
        n = float(input("What number?"))
print("The average is", float(sum/nums_len))
```